# Format a number to time like hh:mm

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, format

I have an iput field:

```
<input type="text" name="time" class="time" value="3" />
```

I need that value to be like 03:00

More examples of what I need:

```
1 = 01:00
12 = 12:00
12:2 = 12:20
2:2 = 02:20
02:2 = 02:20
340 = 340:00
340:1 = 340:10
```

You know the rest. How can I solve this in jquery/javascript?

This is what I try in jQuery:

```
$('input').blur(timeFormat);

function timeFormat(e){
    skjema.find('input.tid').each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length != 0){
            var tid = $(this).val().toString();

            if(tid.length == 1){

                $(this).val(String("0" + tid));

            }
            if(tid.indexOf(':') == -1){
                $(this).val(tid.toString() + ':00');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is what I have made now and it does the job, but it is somewhat bulky :)

```
function timeFormat(e){
    skjema.find('input.tid').each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length != 0){
            var tid = $(this).val().toString();
            tid = (tid.length == 1) ? '0' + tid : tid;
            tid = (tid.indexOf(':') == -1) ? tid + ':00' : tid;
            if(tid.indexOf(':') != -1){
                var arr = tid.split(':');
                var before = arr[0].toString();
                var after = arr[1].toString();
                before = (before.length == 0) ? '00' : before;
                before = (before.length == 1) ? '0' + before : before;
                after = (after.length == 0) ? '00' : after;
                after = (after.length == 1) ? after + '0' : after;
                console.log('before: ' + before + ' After: ' + after);
                tid = before + ':' + after;
            }
        }
        $(this).val(tid);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with some simple regex:

```
function time( str ) {
    if ( !/:/.test( str ) ) { str += ':00'; }
    return str.replace(/^\d{1}:/, '0$&').replace(/:\d{1}$/, '$&0' );
}
```

If you want to make sure only the expected format is accepted, add this line at the top of the function:

```
if ( /[^:\d]/.test( str ) ) { return false; }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/MzgMz/

Answer (score 2):

YOu can try something like this using [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library:-

```
 var dateString = "12";
 var date = new Date.parseExact(dateString, "hh:mm");
```

Comment: I think it needs a certain library here.

Comment: Yes you need to have datejs library. Updated my answer as well

Comment: I tried it and found out about the datejs library. But I dont think i will do me any good. Updating my question.

Answer (score 1):

check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vcQjb/)

```
$('input').blur(timeFormat);

function timeFormat(e){ 
    $("div").find('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length != 0){
            var tid = $(this).val().toString();

            if(tid.length == 1){

                $(this).val(String("0" + tid));

            }
            if(tid.indexOf(':') == -1){
                $(this).val(tid.toString() + ':00');
            }
            if(tid.indexOf(':') == 2){
                $(this).val(tid.toString() + '0');
            }
        }
    });
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<title>Insert Colon in the Time Format</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function formatTime(objFormField){
intFieldLength = objFormField.value.length;

if(intFieldLength==2 || intFieldLength == 2){
     objFormField.value = objFormField.value + ":";
     return false;
    } 
}
</script>

Enter time <input type="text" maxlength="5" minlength="5" onKeyPress="formatTime(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo:

1. `val` ← value from field (`$('.time').val()`)
2. `colonPos` ← position of `.` in `val`
3. If `colonPos` equals -1, `result` ← `padZero(val) + ':00'`
4. Else, `result` ← `padZero(val[:colonPos]) + ':' + padZero(val[colonPos + 1:])`

Answer (score 0):

```
function prettyTime(t){
  // will output a time providing leading zeros and minute field
  // (doesn't need jQuery)

  x=t.split(":");

  for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
    x[i] = (x[i]) ? Array(3-x[i].length).join('0') + x[i] : '00';

  return x.join(":");

}

// --

$('input').blur(timeFormat);

function timeFormat(e){
    skjema.find('input.tid').each(function(){

        $(this).val(function(i, v) { return prettyTime(v); })

    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe u can try  [this](http://sajjansarkar.blogspot.com/2012/11/jquery-plugin-to-convert-textbox-to.html) plugin.. Worked for me

**Usage Examples:**

```
$("#tbPlain").timefield();
$("#tb12Hour").timefield({ 'hourFormat': '12'});
$("#tb24Hour").timefield({ 'hourFormat': '24'});
$("#tbWithInvalidHandler").timefield({ 
        'hourFormat': '24',
        'onError'   : function(){
                alert(this.value+' is not a valid time!');
                this.style.backgroundColor='red';
            }
        });
$("#tbOnOff").timefield();
$("#btnTurnOff").click(function(){
                $("#tbOnOff").timefield('turnOffTimeField');
            });
```

**Live Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/bst3cw2g/

Comment: You should add an example here.